# On first tabs first click, the browser view moves up

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb foundation to create simple tabs, as [seen here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/tabs.php#simple3).

Everything works great, but, when I first click another tab, the view from my browser changes. It seems to move up. I think it acts as though the link, with the anchor tag moves it. On subsequent clicks, it doesn't do that though.

Here's my code :

```
<dl class="tabs">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#simple1">Overview</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Location</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Features</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Reviews</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Promotions</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">T&amp;C's</a></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="simple1Tab">
...
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to have been caused by a change in size of the height of the view. The difference in height between tabs seemed to have caused it. This was a hack I found for a different script, but it did the trick

```
/* 'Prevents Jumping Javascript Effect on Tabs and Sorter' */ html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

adding a hash tag and the end of a url makes your browser 'sometimes' go to the top, maybe using javascript for the url could be the solution?